# Which packages and bibliography style do I need to show URL accessed date in BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, packages

I have generated BibTeX file from a webpage by Zotero. The format I got is:

```
@misc{<>,
    title = {<>},
    shorttitle = {<>},
    url = {<>},
    abstract = {<>},
    language = {<>},
    urldate = {<>},
    journal = {<>},
    author = {<>, <>},
    month = <>,
    year = {<>}
}
```

I saved this file as `ref.bib` and used it in my TeX file which looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\author{<>}
\title{<>}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{<>}
This document ...

This discovery\cite{<>} was extraordinary.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

After compiling with `PDFLaTeX` & `BibTeX`, only the `author`, `title`, `month`, `year` have appeared. How to show all of them, especially the `url` and `urldate` of the source? Which style should I use to solve this issue?
TIA
N.B.: I am new in LaTeX. I'm using MikTeX and Texmaker in Windows system.

Comment: The `ieeetr` bibliography style has been around, more or less unchanged, since the early 1980s. Given that URLs were pretty much unheard of back then, it's not all that surprising that the `ieeetr` bibliography style doesn't do anything with fields called `url` and `urldate`. Please tell us if you're free to choose a suitable bibliography style or, alternatively, you must use a specific bibliography style. Incidentallly, if Zotero outputs a `journal` field for entries of type `@misc`, then something is *very wrong* with Zotero.

Comment: Yes, I am free to choose a suitable style. Please suggest me some. 
@Mico it's not from a journal, but from a blog post. Maybe that's why the type is `@misc`!

Comment: In that case, try loading the `apacite` package (with the option `natbibapa` in case you like the `\citet` and `\citep` citation call-out commands) and the `apacite` bibliography style. Do be aware that this bibliography style generates authoryear-style citation call-outs, not numeric-style citation call-outs. (Aside: If a bibliographic entry is a blog post and hence if the entry type `@misc` is used, the field `journal` shouldn't be used under any circumstance. The `journal` field should be used only for the name of an academic-style journal.)

Comment: I didn't know that, @Mico. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Why did you write that you were free to choose a suitable bib style when it’s not the case?

Comment: If you can't modify the style, you can probably get it to show up by adding it to the note field using something like https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/scripting/#add-accessdate-url-for-bibtex

Comment: I am free to choose any bib style. @Mico .
But I want to use a numeric-style which will show url and urdate too.
which style and packages can fulfill my need? 
TIA

Comment: @MubtasimFuad - If you must use a bibliography style that creates numeric-style citation call-outs and that doesn't sort bibliographic entries alphabetically by authors' surnames, you are *not* free to choose any bib style. Anyway, I'm not aware of any bib style that satisfies these requirements, while still being set up to process the fields `url` and `urldate`. Maybe somebody else does.

Comment: I think I just need to switch from BibTeX to BibLaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know yet how to solve this issue in BibTeX.
Just for my own comport, I wanted to use a numeric-bib style which will show url and urdate too. But I couldn't find out the necessary bib style and packages to fulfill my need.
Then I saw it can be done quite easily by using the package `biblatex`.
Here's an example of what I did to solve the issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} % use this package

\author{<>}
\title{<>}
\addbibresource{raf.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{<>}
This document ...

This discovery\cite{<>} was extraordinary.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] 

\end{document}
```

But I couldn't do this way if I was asked to use a specific bibliography style. The submission was just for an online contest and I was free to do any style. That's why I could solve it in this way.