# How can I fix overfull \hbox problem in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, warnings, debugging

The errors aren't creating any problem in my desired output, but what does it mean? 
How can I fix it?

[image]

I will share my tex file if needed.

Comment: This is not an error, it's just log that page 4 contains only float (i.e, figure or tables).

Comment: This seems linked to your bibliography.  Maybe urls overflowing into the margin?

Comment: @Bernard, yes, you are right. Some URLs in my bibliography section are overflowing into the margin!
Please Check my bibliography style here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489731/114006
and kindly help me to fix it.

Comment: It is just  a matter of the `url`  package (loaded by  `biblatex`) which cannot split urls at any character. Try  loading `xurl`.

Comment: Wow! It's solved. Thanks a lot, @Bernard. Kindly help me out to clear little confusions.<br/> 1. Is `\usepackage{url}` now unnecessary as I am using `\usepackage{xurl}`? 
 <br/> 2. What is the need for `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489731/114006)? [The output seems unaffected if I remove that package.]

Comment: 1. Yes, bur it was anyway unnecessary since biblatex loads it. 2. `tocbibind` guarantees that list of tables, list of figures, bibliography, index and even the toc (which is ridiculous, in my opinion – no one reads the toc to find where it is) are in the toc. The `[notoc]` option removes the toc from this list.  If in your case, it doesn't change whatever, just delete it.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Bernard.

Comment: `tocbibind` is not compatible with `biblatex`, though. It won't do anything bad with `biblatex`, but it will not have any effect on whether or not a `biblatex`-produced bibliography goes to the ToC. That is controlled with the `heading` option of `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Related (possible duplicates) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/35864.

Comment: Thank you, @moewe

Comment: Can we close your question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3033/35864?

Comment: Sure, it's your wish. While asking, I actually didn't know what my problem exactly was. I am satisfied with fixing the issue.